# How to resolve context parameter on offer in Sitecore CDP?

Tags: cdp, sitecore-personalize

I have Sitecore CDP Interactive Experience defined based off Decision Model that returns an offer. On offer data I have context parameter `${guest.firstname}` defined but its not resolving its value and returning it as-is in the experience response.

**JSON response:**

```
{
  "decisionOffers": [
    {
      "ref": "616b2261-9cd1-48a1-94c5-e7d00f89b4d5",
      "name": "Harsh-50-USD-Discount",
      "description": "USD 50 Discount",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "attributes": {
        "imageurl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/A0A0A0/FFFFFF/?text=$+50+Off",
        "name": "50% off on Apple Watches ${guest.firstname}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Should this resolve by itself before returning response and how?

**Image:**

[image: Sitecore CDP Experience Response]

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the response from Sitecore Support - basically this functionality is a leftover from an old deprecated feature and will be removed from the UI https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/33786/4825. However, my and x3mxray's workarounds are still valid and will continue working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`ve faced the same issue. Looks like a bug.

My workaround was to move context parameters out of offer:

```
{
<#if (offers)??>
  "decisionOffers": ${toJSON(offers)},
</#if>
"firstName": "${guest.firstName!}"
}
```

Experience response is:

```
{
  "decisionOffers": [
    {
      "ref": "fcde595f-fd78-41db-8b0e-23b5af1f1185",
      "name": "Offer ",
      "description": "Offer ",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "attributes": {
        "imageUrl": "https://icycoupons.com/img/single-offer/womensbest.jpg",
        "title": "Dear ${guest.firstname}, 40% Off Best Coupon!",
        "description": "Save money on things you want with a Women's Best promo code or coupon. Join the Women's Best Rewards Club for Birthday Offers, Early Access to Limited Editions & Surprise Gifts with Every Purchase.",
        "linkUrl": "https://by.wildberries.ru/brands/womens-store"
      }
    }
  ],
  "firstName": "Denis"
}
```

As you can see substitution doesn`t work inside  offer, but works outside. And you can substitute your variablr in HTML markup, like this:

```
<h1>Dear {{firstName}},</h1>
{{#decisionOffers}}
  {{#attributes}}
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-container__image" style='background-image: url("{{imageUrl}}");'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bx-transition-card__body">
       
        <h3>[[Title | string | {{title}} | {required:true, group: Title, order: 1}]]</h3>
        <p>[[Description | text | {{description}} | {required:true, group: Description, order: 1}]]</p>
        <div class="options-container">
            <a id="bx-transition-card--secondary" class="options-container__secondary">[[Dismiss Text | string | No Thanks | {required:true, group: Secondary Button, order: 1}]]</a>
            <a id="bx-transition-card--primary" class="options-container__primary" href="{{linkUrl}}">[[CTA Text | string | Yes Please | {required:true, group: CTA Button, order: 1}]]</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/attributes}}
{{/decisionOffers}}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

##### Update on 15/03/2023

I raised this with Sitecore Support and got the following response:

> Functionality related to context parameters in offers is a leftover from the old Engage 1 feature which is now deprecated. **Context parameters for offers were not designed to work with Freemarker or Decision Tables.** Thus, it was decided to remove all UI elements that contain references to this functionality as well as update the documentation to avoid further confusion.
>
> Nevertheless, since you have an interest in this functionality, I submitted a feature request to our development team regarding the same.

##### Workaround

This is a workaround I found while trying to resolve the same problem - a context parameter in offer was not replaced automatically and instead it was returned as simple text:

> Welcome ${guest.firstName}

I managed to make it work by using the `?interpret` built-in method that exists in FreeMarker. It can execute string variables as FreeMarker templates.
Here is an example of how an offer title can be accessed and interpreted in a full stack experience:

```
{
<#if (offers)??>
    "offer": {
        "title": "<@(offers[0].attributes.Title)?interpret />",
        "description": "<@(offers[0].attributes.Description)?interpret />",
        "imageUrl": "${offers[0].attributes.ImageUrl}"
    }
</#if>
}
```

This is just a temporary workaround as I would expect Sitecore CDP/Personalize to replace the context variables in offers automatically.

Another thing I noticed is that Offers editing UI suggests variables `${guest.firstname}` and `${guest.lastname}` in lowercase while FreeMarker template expects them in camel case.

[image: Offers editing UI]

So I had to tweak the variable manually like this to use the correct field name: `${guest.firstName}`.